# how to add<a> tag with laravel routing to a table rowusing jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

How do I add a tag to a table row with Laravel routing using jQuery?

**exam.blade.php**

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ URL::Route('editAdminexamtimes', array('cid' => $exam->cls_id, 'id' => $exam->id )) }}">Time Table</a>
    <a href="{{ URL::Route('editExam', array('cid' => $exam->cls_id,'id' => $exam->id )) }}">Edit</a>
    <a href="{{ URL::Route('deleteExam', $exam->id) }}"
       onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure to delete this item?')){ return false; }" 
       title="Delete this Item"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> </a>
</td>
```

Can I write this above code using jQuery?

Comment: Do you mean pick up the url/anchor with Ajax? In that case you still need a path for that request.

Comment: i want like this$("#datatable").find('tbody').append(<td><a href=??>Time Table</a></td>).but what i write in href??

Comment: You will always need to fetch that url some way or another. Be it by pre setting a js variable in your template or even grabbing it through ajax. You're the developer, you make the rules.

Comment: i don't know how to fetch the url other than the ajax.Is following is correct??   var url = URL::Route('editAdminexamtimes', array('cid' => $exam->cls_id, 'id' => $exam->id )) }}" then use this variable in href.

Answer (score 0):

exam.blade.php

```
<td>
<a href="{{URL::Route('editAdminexamtimes', array('cid'=> $exam->cls_id ,'id' => $exam->id ))}}">Time Table</a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="editItem">Edit</a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="deleteItem" data-url="{{url('/')}}" title="Delete this Item" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
</a>
</td>
```

Delete using jquery

```
$('#deleteItem').on('click',function(){
        var token = $(this).data('token');
        var base_url = $(this).data('url');
        if(confirm('Are you sure to delete this item?')){
          $.ajax({
                url:baseurl+'/delete/'+$exam->id,
                type: 'DELETE',
                data: { _token :token},
                success:function(msg){
                   alert("success");
                }
          });
         }
         else
           return false;
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.i also need to append timetable,edit,delete links using jQuery

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="TimeTable">Time Table</a>. using ajax url : base_url+'/editAdminexamtimes/'+$exam->id;

Answer (score 0):

I've created a helper class ([gist here](https://gist.github.com/Tomanow/cd795632ed94f52bf0ec)) specifically for dealing with tables and creating such action links. The helper will create all the table rows (including table header) with the `$allowed` model fields. When looping through the table rows, the `createLinks()` function in the helper class simply passes a `$model_name` for resource and the actual `$obj`.

So if your model is a `form`, and you passed the view an array of `$forms` from your controller, you can use the following:

#### The Route

```
Route::resource('form', 'FormController');
```

#### The View (ie: `form/index.blade.php`)

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $forms {array} Form
 */

// Fields to show in table as name => label for table header
$allowed = array(
        'id'          => 'ID',
        'name'        => 'Name',
        'description' => 'Description',
        'created_at'  => 'Created',
        'updated_at'  => 'Updated'
);

// Optional extras like a model name for action links
$extras = array(
    'model' => 'form'
); ?>

<table class="make-datatable table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered" id="forms-table">
    {!! TableHelper::createTable($forms, $allowed, $extras) !!}
</table>
```

#### The Helper Class

```
<?php
/**
 * Class TableHelper
 * @author Tom W. DeBerardine
 */
class TableHelper
{
    public static function createHeaderRow($obj, $allowed, $extras = array())
    {
        $attributes = $obj[0]['attributes'];
        $html       = '<thead><tr>';

        foreach ($allowed as $attribute => $nice_name) {
            if (array_key_exists($attribute, $attributes)) {
                $html .= '<th>' . $nice_name . '</th>';
            }
        }

        if (array_key_exists('model', $extras)) {
            $html .= '<th>Actions</th>';
        }

        $html .= '</tr></thead>';

        return $html;
    }

    public static function createTableBody($obj, $allowed, $extras = array())
    {
        $html = '<tbody>';
        foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
            $html .= '<tr>';
            foreach ($allowed as $fkey => $field) {
                $html .= '<td>' . $value->$fkey . '</td>';
            }

            if (array_key_exists('model', $extras)) {
                $html .= TableHelper::createLinks($extras['model'], $value);
            }

            $html .= '</tr>';
        }
        $html .= '</tbody>';

        return $html;
    }

    public static function createLinks($model_name, $obj)
    {
        $html = '<td>';
        $html .= '<a href="' . route($model_name . '.' . 'edit', [$obj]) . '">' . 'Edit' . '</a>&nbsp;';
        $html .= '<a href="' . route($model_name . '.' . 'show', [$obj]) . '">' . 'Show' . '</a>';

        $html .= \Form::open(array('url' => route($model_name . '.' . 'destroy', [$obj]), 'method' => 'delete'));
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" onclick="
            if (!confirm(\'Delete this object?\')) { return false; }"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</button>';
        $html .= \Form::close();
        $html .= '</td>';

        return $html;
    }

    public static function createTable($obj, $allowed, $extras = array())
    {
        return TableHelper::createHeaderRow($obj, $allowed, $extras) . TableHelper::createTableBody($obj, $allowed, $extras);
    }
}
```

#### The Output

```
<table class="make-datatable table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered" id="forms-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Updated</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Campaign 1</td>
        <td>First campaign form</td>
        <td>2016-01-01 15:59:39</td>
        <td>2016-01-01 16:53:34</td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://demo.com/form/1/edit">Edit</a>&nbsp; 
            <a href="http://demo.com/form/1">Show</a>
            <form method="POST" action="http://demo.com/form/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="aURptz3LWIZMXwefq1HYnvi4kteGsIObloBPWlgR">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" onclick="
            if (!confirm('Delete this object?')) { return false; }"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete
                </button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This assumes you have working controller actions for the `show`, `edit` and `delete` functionality. If you want the delete button to submit the form via ajax, simply intercept the `submit()` event and put a check in your `delete` controller action for if the request is ajax (`if( $request->ajax() ){ ...`) to send a json response.